# Local-Dynamodb unit testing; GSI not updating

Tags: docker, amazon-dynamodb

I have a test case which seems flaky; 
Following is a workflow I am following and currently observed only on `amazon/local-dynamodb` as available on dockerhub

-- Create a table with 8 secondary indexes
-- In one step add 2 entries as such

```
[{"id": 1, "status": "INCOMPLETE", "team": "A"},
 {"id": 2, "status":"INCOMPLETE", "team": "B"}]
```

-- In step 2 add / update as follows

```
[{"id": 1, "status": "DONE", "team": "C"},
 {"id": 2, "status":"INCOMPLETE", "team": "B"}, 
 {"id": 3, "status":"INCOMPLETE", "team": "A"}]
```

In the test I am checking that count of done: this works correctly  --uses a GSI

In second assert I am checking count of team "A"; this comes out to 2!!! --uses another GSI

This test is becoming flaky; every time a new table is created in local-dynamodb (available on docker-hub) and then queried. It runs most of the times and fails some times after the second assert; 
The table GSI never gets updated.

Comment: Are you creating 8 GSI's ?

Comment: yes, I need it for the query pattern, haven't expressed all the fields there ^

Comment: It is hard to predict what might be happening with just this information. It might help if you can add something that you think can be useful in further debugging.

Are you running the tests in parallel ?

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande, no it is just one large test.. 
Ack, ill try to debug it more.

Comment: turned out a mistake from my end while preparing the input data; I totally forgot that set is not ordered in Python!!!

Comment: cool. I guess in general code shouldn't rely on order of elements in set

Comment: however, as this is data generated for unit tests, I use the liberty